# Why is my webcam not detected during a Skype video call?

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, skype, conferencing

When I open Skype, Settings->Audio and Video, I see my camera working, and I see the sample video from it. Yet as soon as I join a video call, then suddenly Skype says it can't detect a camera.

Can anyone help with why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you using and are you using inbuilt or external webcam?

Try re-installing your  Skype . Use either latest version if you have an older version or use a newer version if you are using a older one

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and a built-in cam, and Skype has just updated itself to what I presume is the latest version.

Comment: Did you try above? If the previous version of version was working correctly, downgrade should help you.